# Google maps SDK not working in flutter release version

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to implement Google Maps feature in my Flutter app. I have done all the configuration for it including enabling the Maps SDK for Android in the google cloud console.
Since my backend is hosted on a server I had to configure it as **IP Address** in the google cloud platform so my backend can read it.

[image]

But the problem is that, this way it works only for the debug mode. And even using `flutter run --release` the app works pretty fine. But once I build the apk and test it, the app does not show the map.

Now once I tried to change the configuration in the google cloud platform and set it as **Android App** instead and added the necessary entries (package name and SHA-1 key), my backend sent this as a response and the api does not work at all:

> { "error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not
> authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address
> **.**.***.***, with empty referer", "results": [], "status": "REQUEST_DENIED" }

I'm really stuck at this point, I double-checked all the code config related and some solutions on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me! Is there any way to fix this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you by any means using different APIs with that same API key?

Comment: But I would really suggest that you file a support case for this, so that they can take a look at how you are implementing your keys and also for you to avoid posting sensitive stuff here in Stack Overflow. Link here for guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: It was actually some configuration that needed to be fixed in the google cloud platform, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I had to remove any restrictions used for this key in the google cloud platform.

Comment: Still do make sure that you set restrictions to secure your API keys / project as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices. To avoid some headaches in the future